# ActiveAdmin "Add New" Button is not working for has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, nested-forms

I'm working on a project and I need to use nested form in ActiveAdmin, I'm following the docs but I think there's a bug in the latest version of ActiveAdmin. I'm using rails 4 so I need to use the gem directly from github (`gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'`).

Here is my code:

```
 form do |f|
    f.inputs "Mission" do
      f.input :level
      f.input :points
      f.input :title
      f.input :description
    end

    f.has_many :requirements do |r|
      r.input :kind, as: :select, collection: %w(text video image)
      r.input :count
      r.input :description, as: :text
    end

    f.actions
  end
```

and this is actually generating an "Add New Requirement" button at the bottom of the form but
when I click on it the button is just taking me up to the top page (it has a # as the href value) and not generating the form.

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I downloaded the source code, searched for has_many.js.coffee, turned it into play JS, pasted it in a new file and included it in my manifest and it worked.

Comment: Did you add accepts_nested_attributes_for :requirements in your Mission model ?

Comment: That was 4 month ago. I dont remember. I guess that should be solved right now.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. It doesn't automatically include the JS needed for the functionality. Try adding this in 'config/initializers/active_admin.rb':

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  config.register_javascript 'active_admin/lib/has_many.js'
end
```